# I have a proplem implementing the strategy pattern with the processing library

Tags: java, processing

I do the module 6 assignment for the "Object Oriented Programming in Java" coursera course. I implemented the functionality that when a user pressed the right mouse button on a earthquake marker the map will show the earthquake markers who have a similar magnitude.

Implementing this in one class works fine. But when I try to use the pattern I get a null pointer exception. The EarthQuakeCityMap class looks like this:

```
public class EarthquakeCityMap extends PApplet 
{
    // The map
    protected UnfoldingMap map;

    // Markers for each earthquake
    protected List<Marker> quakeMarkers;

    // NEW IN MODULE 5
    protected CommonMarker lastClicked;

    private MouseClickBehavior mouse_behavior_;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked()
    {
        if(mouseButton == LEFT)   LeftClick();
        if(mouseButton == RIGHT)  RightClick();
    }

    private void RightClick()
    {
        SetClickBehavior(new RightClick());
        mouse_behavior_.MouseClick();
    }

    public void SetClickBehavior(MouseClickBehavior obj_bahavior){ mouse_behavior_ = obj_bahavior; }
}
```

The MouseClickBehavior interface is the following:

```
package module6;
public interface MouseClickBehavior { void MouseClick(); }
```

The RightClick class in which the exception occurs is:

```
public class RightClick implements MouseClickBehavior
{
    public RightClick()
    {
        map_ = new EarthquakeCityMap();
        magnitude_ = -2.0f;
        begin_ = end_ = 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public void MouseClick()
    {
        CheckEarthquakesForMagnitude();
    }

    private void CheckEarthquakesForMagnitude()
    {
        if (map_.lastClicked != null) {
            map_.unhideMarkers();
            map_.lastClicked = null;
    }
    else {
        for(Marker m : map_.quakeMarkers)
        {
            EarthquakeMarker marker = (EarthquakeMarker) m;
            if (!marker.isHidden() && marker.isInside(map_.map, map_.mouseX, map_.mouseY))
            {
                magnitude_ = marker.getMagnitude();
                map_.lastClicked = marker;
                break;
            }
        }
        ShowMagnitudeMarkers();
    }
}
    private EarthquakeCityMap map_;
    private float magnitude_;
}
```

Finally the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at RightClick.CheckEarthquakesForMagnitude(RightClick.java:25)
at RightClick.MouseClick(RightClick.java:15)
at EarthquakeCityMap.RightClick(EarthquakeCityMap.java:108)
at EarthquakeCityMap.mouseClicked(EarthquakeCityMap.java:102)
at processing.core.PApplet.mouseClicked(PApplet.java:3149)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleMouseEvent(PApplet.java:2842)
at processing.core.PApplet.dequeueEvents(PApplet.java:2729)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2401)
at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:873)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:690)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:672)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1383)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1277)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1131)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1394)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
```

I have included only the code I thought is relevant to the problem I have. Would be nice if somebody could explain to me why I get the exception and how to implement the behavior without over bloating the EarthquakeCityMap.

Thanks in advance.

Update:
Thanks for all the comments. I have made some changes to my code but to post it all here is too much. I have created a repo if someone is interested to look at the code. The link is [Github repo](https://github.com/athkou/Coursera-module6)

After changing the code and debugging the code I have noticed that when the user right clicks on the map a new RightClick object is initialized but after the constructor is done, his member variable map_ is initialized to null. That is the reason why I get a NPE. Don't know why. Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Stacktrace is showing exception is at `line no.22 in RightClick.java`. Check the variable(s) that you are using on that line is(are) initialized.

Comment: Also, please respect the Java naming conventions. Methods and variables always start with a lowercase letter, and naver contain an underscore.

Comment: This Java code will not compile. Provide fixed grammar code

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to help you without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't see the `SetClickBehavior()` function, or more importantly, we can't see where you initialize any of your variables. Your NPE is probably caused by a missing initialization, so we need to see what you're initializing them to.